# Add the value into the array using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript. I tried a code like this

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var fruit_kiwi = "Kiwi";
fruits.push(fruit_kiwi);
console.log(fruits);
```

I need the output like this
   "Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango, Kiwi"
 but my output came like this
   "Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango","Kiwi"
Can anyone help me how to join the value into the array?

Comment: Your code works, not sure what the issue is

Comment: Your current code outputs `"Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango, Kiwi"` as you wanted.

Comment: whats wrong in here

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGBWWV?editors=1111 its working

Comment: Hi Andrew....Exactly,I need the code output "Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango, Kiwi"

Comment: You're probably setting your array to `var fruits = ["Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango"]`. Without quotes in between each fruit and the whole thing is a one big string

Comment: @vishnupriya You code already works by adding the "Kiwi" item to the array. Do you want the output to be a single `String` containing all the array items? Then use `.join` (`console.log(fruits.join(', '))`)

Comment: @ Paulquappe I used the push method but my output came like this "Banana, Orange, Apple, Mango", "Kiwi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess all you need is [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var fruit_kiwi = "Kiwi";
fruits.push(fruit_kiwi);
console.log(fruits.join(","));
```